# Is there a relation that is neither reflexive nor transitive nor symmetric or anti-symmetric

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Can anyone help me with this question i got from discrete, perhaps my understanding is not good enough and I've been stuck trying to think of a possible relation that could work.

It asked for a relation on R {a,b,c}

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  A relation on $\{a,b,c\}$ is a subset of the ordered pairs $\{a,b,c\}\times \{a,b,c\}$.  Are you with me so far?

Comment: High level comment (which does not come close to answering the question): relations on $X$ are just subsets of $X \times X$. There is very little that they are required to do, and there are lots of constructions of relations that do not do what the properties you mention require relations to do. There are a number of degrees of freedom here, which may feel like an obstacle to answering the question, but they aren't. They make it easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hardmath**’s comment is right on the money: you need to look at the definitions of reflexivity, antisymmetry, transitivity, and symmetry and see exactly what it takes to ensure that $R$ does **not** have each of these properties. Take them one at a time. It helps to have a diagram of $\{a,b,c\}\times\{a,b,c\}$ in front of you, since $R$ is a subset of that set: you can use it to help you keep track of which of the $9$ possible ordered pairs you want to keep **in** $R$, and which ones you want to keep **out** of $R$. I’ll give you a good start on the task and leave the rest to you to finish.

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\langle a,c\rangle&\langle b,c\rangle&\langle c,c\rangle\\
\langle a,b\rangle&\langle b,b\rangle&\langle c,b\rangle\\
\langle a,a\rangle&\langle b,a\rangle&\langle c,a\rangle
\end{array}$$

- If $R$ is not reflexive, there must be some $x\in\{a,b,c\}$ such that $x\not\mathrel{R}x$. You can pick any of the members of $\{a,b,c\}$ to fill this rôle; let’s pick $a$ and color $\langle a,a\rangle$ blue to indicate that it definitely is not in $R$:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\langle a,c\rangle&\langle b,c\rangle&\langle c,c\rangle\\
\langle a,b\rangle&\langle b,b\rangle&\langle c,b\rangle\\
\color{blue}{\langle a,a\rangle}&\langle b,a\rangle&\langle c,a\rangle
\end{array}$$

- If $R$ is not antisymmetric, there must be some $x,y\in\{a,b,c\}$ such that $x\mathrel{R}y$, and $y\mathrel{R}x$, but $x\ne y$. Let’s try using $a$ and $b$; if that doesn’t work out, we can always back up and try a different pair. Using red to indicate ordered pairs that definitely **are** in $R$, we now have:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\langle a,c\rangle&\langle b,c\rangle&\langle c,c\rangle\\
\color{red}{\langle a,b\rangle}&\langle b,b\rangle&\langle c,b\rangle\\
\color{blue}{\langle a,a\rangle}&\color{red}{\langle b,a\rangle}&\langle c,a\rangle
\end{array}$$

- If $R$ is not transitive, there must be some $x,y,x\in\{a,b,c\}$ such that $x\mathrel{R}y$, and $y\mathrel{R}z$, but $x\not\mathrel{R}z$. Note that $x,y$, and $z$ are not all required to be distinct. We already have such an example just in the ordered pairs whose status vis à vis $R$ has been decided; I leave it to you to find it.
- If $R$ is not symmetric, there must be some $x,y\in\{a,b,c\}$ such that $x\mathrel{R}y$, but $y\not\mathrel{R}x$. I’ll leave this one to you; there are several ways to complete the construction of $R$ so that it is not symmetric.